# Quickfix/N the callbacks ToApp ToAdming is not trigering in Initiator

Tags: quickfixn

I created simple quickfix application:

```
 public static void Main()
    {
        SessionSettings settings = new SessionSettings("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Work\\QFLib\\config\\Config2.txt");
        MyQuickFixApp myApp = new MyQuickFixApp();
        IMessageStoreFactory storeFactory = new FileStoreFactory(settings);
        ILogFactory logFactory = new FileLogFactory(settings);
        var acceptor = new SocketInitiator(
            myApp,
            storeFactory,
            settings,
            logFactory);
        bool sendlogon = true;
        acceptor.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            if(sendlogon)
            myApp.SendLogonRequest(myApp.session.SessionID);
            sendlogon = false;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        acceptor.Stop();
    }

}
```

The problem server is not getting requests, and not sending response. The configs looks okay and generated message also looks good. I also sending generated message via TCP client and in that case on server I get parse error and no response.
The config file:[Config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35CrD.png)
The logs:[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IxO0.png)

Comment: Just a general note: you do not need to send session level messages, e.g. logon, by yourself. Quickfix will do that for you.

Comment: What does the message in the logs mean?

Comment: The message in logs mean: the remote side closed the connection. How to setup the password in Quickfix logon message that quickfix do automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Cristoph John answered I didn't need to send logon.
I just needed to add code to autologin:

```
public void ToAdmin(Message msg, SessionID sessionID) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ToAdmin " + msg);
        if (msg.GetType() == typeof(QuickFix.FIX44.Logon))
        {
            msg.SetField(new Password("Password"));
            msg.SetField(new ResetSeqNumFlag(true));
        }
    }
```